# Функция, в которую заложены строки

Tags: python, list

Привет, во-первых у меня тут используется клиент, скачанный с github, поэтому не знаю, совсем ли уместно задавать вопрос по коду, который вы, наверно не сможете проверить, но тем не менее:

```
client = Client(apiKey, apiSecret)
order_sell = client.get_buy_orders('DENT-ETH',group=8, limit=1)
print (order_sell)
```

Вывод данных с этого кода такой:

```
[[1.896e-05, 131847.863, 2.5051094]]
```

"двойной" словарь с тремя значениями. В скобках заданы параметры: первый - название валюты, по которой выводятся значения, group - количество знаков после запятой, limit - кол-во словарей в глубь по одной валюте, это не важно.

Меня интересует, как вместо строки  'DENT-ETH' ("type symbol: string") подставить функцию, чтобы инфа выводилась по многим валютам.

Например:

```
pair = ['LEND-ETH', 'ETH-BTC', 'LEND-BTC']
order_sell = client.get_buy_orders(pair,group=8, limit=1)
```

Почему то выдает данные только по первой из перечисленных строк 'LEND-ETH'.

Comment: Во-первых, [[1.896e-05, 131847.863, 2.5051094]] - это не словарь, а список. Во-вторых, на ваш вопрос могут ответить только разработчики библиотеки, которую вы используете. Читайте документацию на эту и другие функции. Если там реализована такая возможность, вы найдёте способ, как то сделать. Наверно, вы можете посылать запросы в цикле на каждую валюту, правда, это может занимать много времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по [описанию функции `get_buy_orders(self, symbol, group=None, limit=None)`](http://python-kucoin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/kucoin/client.html):

```
:param symbol: Name of symbol e.g. KCS-BTC
:type symbol: string
```

параметр `symbol` может быть строкой, но не списком строк.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
pairs = ['LEND-ETH', 'ETH-BTC', 'LEND-BTC']
result = [client.get_buy_orders(pair,group=8, limit=1) for pair in pairs]
```